# Android Listview OnDragListener Item Position On Drop

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop, android-adapter, ontouchlistener

I attached a listener on my listview in my Main Activity as such:

myListView.OnDragListener(...);

Inside getView() of my Custom Adapter, I have an onTouchListener which starts the **DragShadowBuilder** which renders an image of that specific Listview item which can follow my finger around.

What I need to do back in the Main Activity is to somehow tell which "position" of myListView am I dropping the image in. How can I do this?

I've tried setting Tags in the custom adapter, but the problem with that is that the entire listview is the View for onDragListener so it can't differentiate between the items inside the listview. Too bad I can't use onItemClickListener...

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You need to show your code for this since there is no obvious best way to "tell which position". If too much code, perhaps post them onto Github.

Comment: Also, I could not tell from your post what is working now. Do you have the Adapter code already and code for getView()? or did you have a different approach?  Anyway this is the reason why we need to see code if you want help.